# Heroku hosting for Adonuxt (AdonisJS & NuxtJS)

Tags: heroku, vue.js, nuxt.js, adonis.js

I use **Heroku** to host my **Adonuxt** (*Adonis.JS + Nuxt.JS + Vue.JS*) application, I've a problem with this host, I've a request timeout when I visit the webpage.

The build is finished and state of dynos is up.

> 2018-01-24T11:46:30.346430+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12
>   desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=dev.domain.com
>   request_id=32a85fbc-54f8-405c-99e1-b6e0s8e7b969 fwd="195.200.117.30"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30003ms status=503 bytes=0
>   protocol=http

Webpage give me **Application Error** after 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your NuxtJS app is routing to the correct domain. From the log above it seems that your app is routing to dev.domain.com, which does not seem like the correct domain.

Comment: domain.com is an example. I put the right domain ;)